# SubForm that is dynamically filled with other subforms in VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to create a popup form that contains a list of dynamically created subforms. The number of subforms is determined by the user in the parent form.

Here is a sketch to illustrate what I want to do. The user can change the value of "Num Branches" to be between 2 and 10. This number is in turn reflected in the number of subforms created in the scrollable box below. The subforms are all from the same and I outlined them in red. [image]
I have a few questions about how to do this

- Can there be multiples of one sub-form?
- If the above question is no, and I have to dynamically create each control, do I need to be concerned about the 754 dynamically created controls limit mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31301469/7254514
- Could someone give me an example of a loop that demonstrates how to dynamically create these subforms all inside of a scrollable box? I suppose The only property that will change during each for loop is the "top" property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to dynamically create the subform controls (since creating controls = switching to design view, requires an exclusive lock on the database, etc.)

You can't use something like a continuous form with multiple instances of the subform, since Access doesn't allow subform controls on continuous forms.

My approach would be to have 10 (your max) subform controls on the form, hide them all, and dynamically assign them to specific source objects.

Pseudocode:

```
Dim numBranches As Long
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 to numBranches
   Me.Controls("subform" & i).Visible = True
   Me.Controls("subform" & i).Form.Filter = "branch = " & i 'Appropriate filter here
   Me.Controls("subform" & i).Form.FilterOn = True
Next i
```

Comment: I like this approach but let me see if I understand it. So in my main popup form I would have 10 empty subform controls that are hidden. In your pseudocode, these would be named subform1, subform2, etc. I would then populate these empty subforms when the popup form is opened or when the NumBranches value changes. The populated ones get set to visible. What exactly goes in the subform sourceobjects? Would this be the static form I created in design view?

Comment: Ah, you're displaying the same form multiple times. I was thinking multiple forms. In that case, you don't need the `.SourceObject` part (that's usually the form name), but you can use filters. Note that you can clear the `.SourceObject` for all forms, and only set it for the ones you display to optimize performance. I've adjusted my answer to something more appropriate

Comment: Okay cool. So the filter would be like a record in the database that you want that particular subform control to represent?

Comment: Yes, it's just an SQL `WHERE` clause, minus the `WHERE`